# Syntax error in pandas - referring column with space and parenthesis

Tags: python, pandas

one of my csv headers is 'TEMPERATURE (C)' (without the ' of-curse)

and i'm trying to do this kind of command:

```
df1['Average Temp'] = df.'TEMPERATURE (C)'.resample('H', how='mean')
```

and getting invalid syntax error. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
df1['Average Temp'] = df['TEMPERATURE (C)'].resample('H', how='mean')
```